# How do I restrict Slack app to retrieve users info from only private channel where it is added?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a slack app which is requesting a permission users:read , users.read.email. This app will be added to a private channel say #xyz. I do not want this app to retrieve information from any public channel and be limited to extact the user info where this app is added(#xyz here).
With users.read scope this app can call users.list api (list all users in a Slack team) and get the info of users in my workspace.

How can I handle this to limit the response from the private channel where it is added?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to prevent data from public channels to appear when calling the `users.list` method. It would also be difficult to filter data based on channel id because this method does not return channel data. You would need to make a call to `conversations.list` and filter out all private channels. When using your bot token, you will only see private channel data for channels that your bot is a member of. Check for the `is_private:true` flag to determine whether a channel is private.

Then for each private channel you could then call the `conversations.members` method to get a list of user ids for all the users in that channel. You'd then need to call `users.info` on each user id that's returned.

Not the most elegant way to go about it but I can't think of an easier way I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sandra, yeah this is potentially the workflow to go for. Appreciate your solution:) Only thing I am afraid here is the api call to users.info at the end. Since users.info api will require the scope of users.read, this will again put us on the risk that the bot can call users.list api as it only requires users.read scope to function.

Comment: Other solution I can think of here is - 1) Creating a separate workspace for this app to avoid all risks.  Do you know the difference in response from admin.users.list(List users in workspace) and users.list (List users in a Slack team)?? Can we have multiple Slack team in a workspace??

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand. Why would the bot calling `users.list` be a risk?There is really no chance that would happen unless you intentionally call the method. How would crating a separate workspace just for the bot resolve your problem? The admin* methods can only be used by Enterprise Grid Slack instances. You can't have multiple Slack teams in a single workspace. 1 workspace = 1 team, otherwise you'd need to be on an Enterprise Slack instance. Maybe if you provide more details about your use case?